# Can't see Snowsight schema browser

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the [Snowsight documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-gs.html), it looks like there should be an option to browse the schema:

[image]

I'm not seeing that:

[image]

Is there some setting I need to adjust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is actually showing old information and the "Schema" tab is no longer present in Snowsight UI.
Have requested for the documentation to be updated.

Comment: In a demo video that I saw from Snowflake, it looks like the Schema Browser allowed searching for tables and columns throughout the schema. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The schema is present and should be on the left side like in the screenshot below:

[image]

What role are you using?

Comment: The schema is visible. I'm referring to the schema browser that is referenced in the documentation. Videos from Snowflake show that you can use the schema browser to search for tables or columns.

Comment: Has the UI been updated recently? I'm now seeing a search bar above the schema, which doesn't appear in your screenshot.